# Jboss using Self Signed Cert instead of imported trusted Cert

Tags: ssl, cryptography, ssl-certificate, jboss7.x, keystore

I have a problem whereby JBoss AS 7 is using / exposing my self signed certificate and not the certificate signed by the GoDaddy Certificate Authority to the client / browser.

I tried to create a separate keystore (truststore) specifically for the certificates 
*** In the hopes that the `certificate-file` *** attribute will force JBoss to use the certificate chain in the `certificate-file` attribute instead of using the self signed cert for the generated private key.

The `KeyIdentifier` is also correct / matches for the CA cert vs Private Key (Was my first concern).

**Why is JBoss not looking for the most valid certificate in the cert chain (other aliases)? Also, by cert chain I mean aliases.**

**Could my problem be that JBoss is not treating the aliases as the chain but rather the "objects" in each chain as the chain and that is why its not making use of the "more valid" certificate?**

**If that is the case, how do I force the correct certificate into the alias as a new object? Hopefully JBoss / Java will then present the more valid cert.**

Comment: Have you imported the entire chain up to the root certificate? Can you retrieve the private key entry programatically from the key store? Java is a bit choosy in accepting something as private key entry - it needs the private key and the entire chain up to the root certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Everything I did was sort off correct.

It seems like downloading the certs straight from Godaddy and using them "as is" creates an issue with the Java keystore.

I imported the certificates from Godaddy into my Mac Keychain Access application.
Then individually exported the certificates in cer (Binary DER) format.
Then imported the certificates starting with the root and working my way down the chain (each with their own alias, except for the bottom one).

Then lastly imported the signed / validated certificate against the PrivateKey/SelfSigned certificate alias in the keystore and tada, all was working nicely.

I wasted about 3 hours in Jboss configuration, thinking that there might be something wrong with my configuration.